# jq or python script to delete text after date in json field

Tags: python, json, jq

I have a json file with hundreds of entries such as:

```
{
    "url":"http://example.com/10618/",
    "metatag.eprints.publication":"Journal of Corporate Real Estate",
    "metatag.eprints.title":"Corporate Real Estate Strategy",
    "metatag.eprints.citation":"Adair, P, McGrogan, WS, and Webb, JR (2006) Corporate Real Estate Strategy. Journal of Corporate Real Estate"}
{
    "url":"http://example.com/23552/",
    "metatag.eprints.publication":"European Journal of Cardio-Thoracic Surgery",
    "metatag.eprints.title":"Long-term survival from coronary endarterectomies in coronary artery disease",
    "metatag.eprints.citation":"Aaron, P, Jones, K, Pallin, C, and Nash, R (2012) Long-term survival from coronary endarterectomies in coronary artery disease. European Journal of Cardio-Thoracic Surgery"}
```

Could anybody help write a jq or python script which, for every block, would alter the "metatag.eprints.citation" so that all text after the date is deleted?

So the above blocks would become:

```
{
    "url":"http://example.com/10618/",
    "metatag.eprints.publication":"Journal of Corporate Real Estate",
    "metatag.eprints.title":"Corporate Real Estate Strategy",
    "metatag.eprints.citation":"Adair, P, McGrogan, WS, and Webb, JR (2006)"}
{
    "url":"http://example.com/23552/",
    "metatag.eprints.publication":"European Journal of Cardio-Thoracic Surgery",
    "metatag.eprints.title":"Long-term survival from coronary endarterectomies in coronary artery disease",
    "metatag.eprints.citation":"Aaron, P, Jones, K, Pallin, C, and Nash, R (2012)"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jq '.["metatag.eprints.citation"] |= match(".*?\\\)").string // .'`

Needs jq 1.5. What this does is set the value of `metatag.eprints.citation` to the result of matching itself to the regex `.*?\)`, which will match everything before the first closing parenthesis. If there was no closing parenthesis for whatever reason, we use the alternative operator `//` to set the value back to whatever it was.

Comment: Thanks @Santiago Lapresta. How would I 'cat' this to a new file? I had used a script like this before: cat staff-output-solr-index.json| jq -c 'select(.url|contains("#")|not )' > cleaned-staff-index.json

Comment: @KoreMike simply pipe the output from the command into a file.
`cat my-ugly-old-file.json | jq '.["metatag.eprints.citation"] |= match(".*?\\\)").string // .' > my-fancy-citations.json`

Comment: Thanks @Victor Bjelkholm. That's exactly what I tried but I was getting an Invalid escape (while parsing '"\\\)"') error. So I removed one of the \ and the command ran ok. However the output file is coming up empty. Can you try testing it using a test json file with the data from the first code block in the original question?

Comment: The amount of backslashes needed is probably dependent on the specific escaping rules of the shell you're using. @VictorBjelkholm's answer is correct, and I did try it (successfully!) with the code block you provided. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Santiago Laperesta I think my problem was because of the indented code as mentioned in the thread with Padraic above. Sounds like the solution is correct as you say. Haven't been able to test it yet because I need to rebuild jq with oniguruma

Answer (score 2):

Once you format is like your question, you can use `itertools.groupby` to group by the opening bracket, join the lines with str.join and use json.loads to get a dict, then it is simply a matter of accessing by key and writing the updated data to a tempfile. Finally using `shutil.move` to replace the original file, if you want a brand new file just change the `NamedTemporaryFile` to using `open`:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move
from itertools import groupby

import json

with open("in.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    for k, v in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.lstrip().startswith("{")):
        if not k:
            d = json.loads("{" + "".join(v))
            v = d["metatag.eprints.citation"]
            d["metatag.eprints.citation"] = v[:v.find(")")+1]
            json.dump(d, out)
            out.write("\n")
move(out.name,"in.txt")
```

in.txt before:

```
{
    "url":"http://example.com/10618/",
    "metatag.eprints.publication":"Journal of Corporate Real Estate",
    "metatag.eprints.title":"Corporate Real Estate Strategy",
    "metatag.eprints.citation":"Adair, P, McGrogan, WS, and Webb, JR (2006) Corporate Real Estate Strategy. Journal of Corporate Real Estate"}
{
    "url":"http://example.com/23552/",
    "metatag.eprints.publication":"European Journal of Cardio-Thoracic Surgery",
    "metatag.eprints.title":"Long-term survival from coronary endarterectomies in coronary artery disease",
    "metatag.eprints.citation":"Aaron, P, Jones, K, Pallin, C, and Nash, R (2012) Long-term survival from coronary endarterectomies in coronary artery disease. European Journal of Cardio-Thoracic Surgery"}
```

in.txt after:

```
{"url": "http://example.com/10618/", "metatag.eprints.publication": "Journal of Corporate Real Estate", "metatag.eprints.citation": "Adair, P, McGrogan, WS, and Webb, JR (2006)", "metatag.eprints.title": "Corporate Real Estate Strategy"}
{"url": "http://example.com/23552/", "metatag.eprints.publication": "European Journal of Cardio-Thoracic Surgery", "metatag.eprints.citation": "Aaron, P, Jones, K, Pallin, C, and Nash, R (2012)", "metatag.eprints.title": "Long-term survival from coronary endarterectomies in coronary artery disease"}
```

If you have to edit it at a later date you can simply loop over the file and `json.loads` each line to get a dict, update with the key again and write to the file. Having one per line will make your life much easier.

If you can have an opening paren before the date you can use a regex to search for the specific substring, 4 digits between parens:

```
r = re.compile("\(\d{4}\)")
for k, v in groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.lstrip().startswith("{")):
    if not k:
        d = json.loads("{" + "".join(v))
        v = d["metatag.eprints.citation"]
        d["metatag.eprints.citation"] = v[:next(r.finditer(v)).end()]
        json.dump(d, out)
        out.write("\n")
```

If you are getting an empty file then your data must actually be one dict per line so it is just a matter of iterating over the file object and applying the same logic:

```
with open("in.txt") as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w", dir=".",delete=False) as out:
    for line in f:
            d = json.loads(line)
            v = d["metatag.eprints.citation"]
            d["metatag.eprints.citation"] = v[:v.find(")")+1]
            json.dump(d, out)
            out.write("\n")
move(out.name,"in.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks Padraic. That actually deletes the entry for metatag.eprints.citation when I only want to delete the text after the date. Would this require a regexp?

Comment: @KoreMike, Ah ok, I will edit, a regex would be required unless the only parens are around the dat?

Comment: I actually trimmed the content in the examples and there are other parentheses after the date

Comment: So always after the date?

Comment: Yes all the other parentheses always appear after the date

Comment: @KoreMike, then str.find and slicing will work fine, I added a regex  but you won't actually need it in your case

Comment: That looks perfect -- I will test it on the file now

Comment: No worries, I presume the key always exists?

Comment: No joy -- I must be using the script incorrectly. As I think your script is suggesting I do, I am renaming my json file to "in.txt". When I run the script on it, the file then comes up totally empty. Am I using it wrong @Padraic Cunningham?

Comment: @KoreMike, definitely, as there is no way you would get an empty file. remove the move(... line and what do you see in the tempfile when you are finished?

Comment: It's now not deleting the content as before, but it is having no effect

Comment: what do you see when you look in the tempfile?

Comment: temp files are coming up empty

Comment: Then you are passing an empty file or do you actually have the json one dict per line? If so the solution is actually a lot simpler

Comment: I don't want to take up any more of your time with this @Padraic Cunningham I'll have to keep working at it myself

Comment: @KoreMike, no worries, the only way you could get an empty file is a.) you passed an empty file, b.) the data is one json object per line or you have an actual space before the `{` in your file, the last part handles `b`, I will edit to handle c

Comment: You were right @Padraic Cunningham. One of the text editors had added a tabbed indent to the whole file which I hadn't noticed! Thanks for the  code, dude